# I need to retrieve the vaL1 in c# using ,search by red and blue value and find two values

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql, .net

This value (`val1`) I'm passing through url (I mean this operation as jobong filter option in checkbox list, filtering by selection index then passing through another page and retrieve through database):

Default Page 3: `/WebSite4/Default4.aspx?vaL1=blue,red`

This retrieving form page to view in page.

Default Page 2:

```
public void grid()
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from lady_cloth where color in('" + Request.QueryString["vaL1"] + "')", con);

    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
    da1.Fill(ds3);
    con.Close();
    if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds3;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Are you getting an error, incorrect results, or is there another problem? Also **[BEWARE OF SQL INJECTION](http://bobby-tables.com/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not separating your items, so your SQL ends up looking like:

```
select * 
from lady_cloth 
where color in('blue,red')
```

Whereas what you would really want is

```
select * 
from lady_cloth 
where color in('blue','red')
```

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later then I would recommend using [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The first step would be to create your type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

I tend to just create generic types that can be easily reused, but this would be your call.

Then in your method you would need to split your values into an array and add them to a datatable:

```
var colourTable = new DataTable();
colourTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
var colours = Request.QueryString["vaL1"].Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < colours.Length; i++)
{
    var newRow = colourTable.NewRow();
    newRow[0] = colours[i];
    colourTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

You can then add this table to your command as a parameter:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM lady_clock WHERE Color IN (SELECT Value FROM @Colours)"
cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
var parameter = new SqlParameter("@Colours", SqlDbType.Structured);
parameter.Value = colourTable;
parameter.TypeName = "dbo.StringList";
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Finally, You can reduce your code by just initialising the SqlDataAdapter with your SQL and connection:

```
public void grid()
{

    var colourTable = new DataTable();
    colourTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
    var colours = Request.QueryString["vaL1"].Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < colours.Length; i++)
    {
        var newRow = colourTable.NewRow();
        newRow[0] = colours[i];
        colourTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM lady_clock WHERE Color IN (SELECT Value FROM @Colours)"
    DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
    {
        var parameter = new SqlParameter("@Colours", SqlDbType.Structured);
        parameter.Value = colourTable;
        parameter.TypeName = "dbo.StringList";
        adapter.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        con.Open();
        da1.Fill(ds3);
    } 
    if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds3;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: i HAVE AN ERROR IN cOLOURS fILED

Comment: I have edited to show the full method that should work. If it does not work still please can you provide more helpful feedback than "I have an error", what the error message is, where it is thrown etc. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=e_commerce;User ID=sa;Password=xxx");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["Item"];
            //Label2.Text = Request.QueryString["Color"];
            //grid();
            var colourTable = new DataTable();
            colourTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
            var colours = Request.QueryString["vaL1"].Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < colours.Length; i++)
            {
                var newRow = colourTable.NewRow();
                newRow[0] = colours[i];
                colourTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

```
        }
    }
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM lady_cloth WHERE color IN (SELECT Value FROM @Colours)";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
    {
        var parameter = new SqlParameter("@Colours", SqlDbType.Structured);
        //parameter.Value = colourTable;
        parameter.TypeName = "dbo.StringList";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        con.Open();
        adapter.Fill(ds3);
    }
    if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds3;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {

    } 

}
```

Comment: Must declare the table variable "@Colours".